# Add users in bulk with csv file

Tags: powershell, csv, active-directory

I am trying to make a script that creates users in bulk from a csv file. I tested the script with 5 users, but get the error message "New-ADUser: A value for the attribute was not in the acceptable range of values." I have been searching everywhere, but can't find the mistake!

```
function Get-RandomCharacters($length, $characters) { 
    $random = 1..$length | ForEach-Object { Get-Random -Maximum $characters.length } 
    $private:ofs="" 
    return [String]$characters[$random]
}

$ADUsers = Import-csv C:\Users\Admin\Users.csv -Delimiter ";"

foreach ($User in $ADUsers)
{
    $Password  = Get-RandomCharacters -length 20 -characters 'ABCDEFGHKLMNOPRSTUVWXYZabcdefghiklmnoprstuvwxyz1234567890!._?/'
    $Username  = $User.GivenName.substring(0,3) + $User.SurName.substring(0,3)
    $Username  = $Username.Replace('æ','ae')
    $Username  = $Username.Replace('ø','o')
    $Username  = $Username.Replace('å','aa')
    $Username  = $Username.ToLower()
    $Username  = $Username.Trim()
    $Email       = $Username + '@ONPremiumIT.com'
    $DisplayName = $User.GivenName + ' ' + $User.SurName

    New-ADUser `
    -Path $User.Path `
    -SamAccountName $Username `
    -UserPrincipalName $Email `
    -Name "$User.GivenName $User.SurName" `
    -GivenName $User.GivenName `
    -Surname $User.SurName `
    -Enabled $True `
    -ChangePasswordAtLogon $false `
    -DisplayName "$Displayname" `
    -Department $Department `
    -AccountPassword (convertto-securestring $Password -AsPlainText -Force)
}
```

csv file:

```
GivenName;SurName;Department;Path
Tobias;Santelmann;it-drift;OU=it-drift,OU=onprit-brukere,DC=sec,DC=core
Maria;Aas;dev-team;OU=dev-team,OU=onprit-brukere,DC=sec,DC=core
Anniken;Arildset;renhold;OU=renhold,OU=onprit-brukere,DC=sec,DC=core
Thea;Urne;regnskap;OU=regnskap,OU=onprit-brukere,DC=sec,DC=core
Marthea;Wichstad;hr;OU=hr,OU=onprit-brukere,DC=sec,DC=core
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error comes from `-Name "$User.GivenName $User.SurName"`, which should have been `-Name "$($User.GivenName) $($User.SurName)"`.

Example:

```
"$User.GivenName $User.SurName"   # --> @{GivenName=Tobias; Surname=Santelmann}.GivenName @{GivenName=Tobias; Surname=Santelmann}.SurName
```

but when using the [Subexpression operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_operators?view=powershell-7.1#subexpression-operator--) `$(..)`, it does what you want:

```
"$($User.GivenName) $($User.SurName)" # --> Tobias Santelmann
```

Also, when using lots of parameters, you can have difficult to spot errors when using those backticks.

I'd suggest using [Splatting](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_splatting) for that:

```
$userParams = @{
    Path                  = $User.Path
    SamAccountName        = $Username
    UserPrincipalName     = $Email
    Name                  = '{0} {1}' -f $User.GivenName, $User.SurName  # or: "$($User.GivenName) $($User.SurName)"
    GivenName             = $User.GivenName
    Surname               = $User.SurName
    Enabled               = $true
    ChangePasswordAtLogon = $false
    DisplayName           = $Displayname
    Department            = $Department
    AccountPassword       = (ConvertTo-SecureString $Password -AsPlainText -Force)
}

New-ADUser @userParams
```

Comment: Thank you! Such a nice tip!

Comment: What does the '{0} {1}' in Name do?

Comment: @Maria.A That is a template string for the `-f` [Format operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_operators?view=powershell-7.1#format-operator--f). The numbers between curly brackets are placeholders that will be replaced by the values after `-f`. It's my favorite way of constructing strings with variables.

Comment: Thank you so much!! I tried it and it worked perfectly! I really want to learn how to write good powershell script, du you have any other suggestions on how I can improve my script?

Comment: Do you know how I can check for duplicates in the username? And if it already exist it adds the number 1 after.

Comment: @Maria.A After you constructed the user samaccountname, check with `Get-ADUser -Filter "SamAccountName -eq '$userName'" -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue`. If that returns `$null`, the user did not already exist. Otherwise add a sequencenumber and test again in a loop. (P.S. This should have been a new question I think..)